Можно ли в грамотной речи использовать словосочетание «довольно издалека»?
Нас видно довольно издалека, как минимум, из-за того мыса мы явно будем видны.
Текст мой лично авторский, потому на сто процентов похожее вряд ли получится найти.

по стилю режет слух + по смыслу тут не очень вяжется одно с другим. Наречие меры с наречием абсолютности, по типу как "сильно запредельный". "достаточно далеко" снимает вопросы

• Мне сочетание "довольно издалека" не режет слух и не кажется архаичным.
Т. Ф. Ефремова относит наречие "издалека" к обстоятельствам места (откуда?).
Говорим же мы спокойно слишком издалека, совсем издалека и очень издалека.
• Современные примеры употребления (в том числе — похожие на 100 %)
То, что это «здесь», было видно довольно издалека (С. Анисимов, 2015).
Поэтому приходилось тащить к реке срубленные стволы довольно издалека (В. Гуров, 2018).
— Олег, ты уже здесь?! — раздался довольно издалека вопрос (Ю. Шилова, 2022).
Кто-то сюда притащил более ста тонн соли, причем довольно издалека и, если верить пробам грунта под валом, очень давно (А. Прокопович, 2014).
— А вы издалека приехали? — спросил Луис, самый старший из них.
— Да, довольно издалека, — ответил Леонард, улыбнувшись.
(К. Кай, 2024)
— С какого расстояния увидят наши плоские плоты наблюдатели с мачт кораблей?
— О! Довольно издалека, — скривился навигатор. — Километров с двадцати.
(Ю. Иванович, 2009)
•• Авторское предложение я бы оформила немного по-другому: избавилась бы от повтора (видно, видны) и заменила бы запятую перед "как минимум" на тире (так читающему становится понятно, что вводное сочетание относится ко второй части предложения).
Получаем:
Нас видно довольно издалека — как минимум, из-за того мыса мы явно будем заметны (различимы).

Редактирование:
Нас видно уже издалека, как минимум, из-за того мыса мы явно будем видны.
Пояснение

Наречие довольно обычно сочетается  с качественными наречиями и прилагательными, обозначая степень признака: довольно весело, довольно большой.

С наречием издалека  только единичные употребления:


Д. Н. Бегичев. Семейство Холмских. Части 5 и 6 (1832-1841)
Добрые родные наши собирались къ намъ, иные даже довольно издалека.
Приехала довольно издалека, не хочет, чтобы в маленьком городке кто-то что-то узнал о её тайнах.Иосиф Гольман, Тревожность и неврозы. Как от них избавиться, 2023
Но сочетание кажется архаичным.

Слух у всех разный – наречию степени не так уж легко сочетаться с обстоятельством места.  Очень издалека? Может, диалектное сочетание?Но на литературное не похоже. Соединение несоединимого. Я так не скажу.  // Но сейчас много писателей, так что надеяться на чистоту языка не приходится.  Все примеры не из классики. //Так что надо доказать грамматическую сочетаемость.

https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/издалека   Таблица сочетаемости отсутствует.  А почему?  Где же она?

"Очень издалека" — Рыбаков, Залыгин, Кассиль, Панова, Фадеев, Каверин, Гайдар, Куприн, Горький, Пришвин, Грин... Куда уж "классичнее"?

Вопрос не мейл: Кто из поэтов/ писателей родился в Москве? Очень много их тут родилось.
Грибоедов, Лермонтов, Вяземский, Герцен, Достоевский, Пастернак, Цветаева, Барто, Трифонов... Сергей Михалков.
Булат Окуджава.
... и так далее.  Москва! Как много в этом звуке
Для сердца русского слилось!
Как много в нем отозвалось…  А. С. Пушкин

Диалог: А вы откуда? – Очень издалека! // Интересно, на каком ресурсе можно проверить сочетаемость слов? А грамматику? Очень издалека доносился шум поезда. Так не говорят. Откуда-то издалека. Два наречия места.

очень издалека кривовато. по типу как очень идеально. совсем издалека примерно как совсем идеально - звучит норм. По-разному бывает

Да все  криво или кривовато. Наречием степени можно измерить качественный, но не обстоятельственный признак.
